# dispaly month names (month-year format)between two dates in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I've a one table which contains resource id and hire date and termination date.
i just want to get a resource id with all the months existed for this resource for a particular date range.
for ex: I've resource ids 1, 2, 3 and there date of hires 21-mar-2014, 3-jan-2014, 4-may-2014 and their term dates 21-jun-2014, 3-may-2014, 4-aug-2014.
i just want to get the results like

```
res_id     months-years
1          mar-2014
1          apr-2014
1          may-2014
1          jun-2014
2          jan-2014
2          feb-2014
2          mar-2014
2          apr-2014
2          may-2014
3          may-2014
3          jun-2014
3          jul-2014
3          aug-2014
```

Comment: Further, how is the table the data is stored in currently set up? Also, what's the need for listing out each month they were there, wouldn't the hire and termination dates be all you really need?

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, show us specifically what you did so we can help you along. You start it, we help. We don't write it for you. Show us the actual code that you've tried, and then describe what happened and what's not right, and then we can help you from there. Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Comment: Do you want to do that in a SQL query or would a PL/SQL function do as well?

Comment: I JUST NEED THAT IN SQL PLSQL.

Comment: select distinct(last_day(to_date(td.TO_DATE + 1 - rownum)))

from all_objects

    ,(-- this is just to easily substitute dates for the example...

      select  FROM_DATE

            ,TO_DATE

      FROM   PRJ_BLB_SLICEREQUESTS where request_name= 'MONTHLYRESOURCEAVAILCURVE'  ) td

where trunc(td.TO_DATE + 1 - rownum,'MM') >= trunc(td.FROM_DATE,'MM')

order by 1             this is the querry i tried, as it will give athe months that will come between two dates. i need this to happen for all the rows af different from_date and to_date for all the resources

Comment: @user3482080 Yelling at people regarding what you need will get you nowhere. Also, edit your original post with the query you posted so that it's formatted properly.

Answer (score 0):

if your table has a date or timestamp then you can do something like:

```
select to_char(date_column, 'mon-yyyy') from your_table;
```

if the date is a varchar2 string then you can remove just the first characters like so:

```
select substr(date_column, instr(date_column, '-')+1) from your_table;
```

Hope it helps.